# How to add subview as popup in uitableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uialertview, uipopovercontroller

I have a table view when the user selects the cell ,i need to show my sub view, is it possible?

I have tried this:

1. I have created subview.
2. initially i have declared it as `hidden` = yes;
3. while user select the cell ,i have gave `hidden` = no for my subview
   but nothing happens .....
4. Any one please help me to find out the solution.

The code i have used;

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [resheduleView bringSubviewToFront:self.view];

    resheduleView.hidden=NO;
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"PopUP Title"
                                                    message:@"This is pop up window/ Alert"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

//    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]init];

    [alert addSubview:resheduleView];




}
```

Comment: Can you please share your code? What you have tried?

Comment: @RupalPatel i have edited my code as per your suggestion?

Comment: `UIAlertView` is not a real view, you just have to user an `UIView` with an `UILabel`

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code if you have added the subview in table view cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      cell1.YOUR_SUB_VIEW.hidden = NO;
}
```

OR

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      UIView *objViewTemp = cell1.YOUR_SUB_VIEW; //Create object of view which you have used
      objViewTemp.hidden = NO;
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample example for your requirement. Try this

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]init];

    cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell : %ld",(long)indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    UIView *vwTemp=[self.view viewWithTag:987654];
    [vwTemp removeFromSuperview];
    vwTemp=nil;

    UIView *vwPopUp=[[UIView alloc]init];
    vwPopUp.tag=987654;
    [vwPopUp setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 100, 290, 300)];
    [vwPopUp setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];


    UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 290, 30)];
    [lbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have selected : %@",cell.textLabel.text];
    [vwPopUp addSubview:lbl];

    [self.view addSubview:vwPopUp];



}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView *vwTemp=[self.view viewWithTag:987654];
    [vwTemp removeFromSuperview];
    vwTemp=nil;
}
```